# Invalid control character in GAE Blobstore upload with form data

Tags: python, google-apps-script, blobstore

As documented in these two bug reports ([1](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10109), [2](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10243)), google app engine's python blobstore is encoding form data as Quoted-Printable on production, but not SDK.

For example, some JSON text is getting broken into lines with **=**

```
...","db_update_datetime":"2014=
-06-04T02:41:27.501470Z","...
```

That = sign after 2014 shouldn't be there and isn't on SDK. The error when trying to load this data is:

```
Invalid control character at: line 1 column 77 (char 76)
```

when trying:

```
json.loads(self.request.get('formData'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is at least a GAE bug in terms of behavior being different on the SDK and production, a workaround is:

```
import quopri
json.loads(quopri.decodestring(self.request.get('formData')))
```